# Bluetooth speaker firmware modification

Tags: firmware-analysis, bluetooth

I don't know if this is the right community to ask this to but I have this speaker and I want to change the startup, shutdown sound effect of it. It is not a chinese BT speaker but a Hama soundbarrel. I can't disassemble it to reveal the circuit board. Any way to pull the firmware to my PC and then push back the modified firmware? I only have an AUX, USB and a Type C port.

Comment: as what device does it appear if it is connected to a PC? And posting pictures of the device label with model# and regulatory information can be a good pointer, too. Depending on the model it can be done but that needs information on whats inside (which can be googled with some base pointers)

Comment: Well if I just connect it to the PC with a type C cable it appears as a sound device in the device manager and I can get the device properties in the device manager

Comment: Take a picture of the label on the device itself, that should give me enough pointers to google around. Also: whats the hardwareid/vendorid of the device under windows?

Comment: The hardwareid is: "BTHENUM\{0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_LOCALMFG&005d", I could only find the link to the product on their website which is: https://www.hama.com/00188217

Comment: Damnit... making it hard to tickle out information. was hoping for a FCC id when i asked for the label on the device (FCC ID points to a US regulation database where some information is mandatory published, often you can gleam off some information on the inner parts there). and no trace of a firmware update file either so far...

Comment: Found out that my speaker has a CE ID not an FCC id.  https://imgur.com/a/5Rg94s8 Here is everything about the speaker that might be useful, these are all I could find. There is a little white piece of sticker on it that might be the CE ID: F3250886

Comment: dead end... no way to get the information from external sources without teardown then... and not even a firmware update as a "hint" for what chip is used.

Answer (score 1):

No, you would have to disassemble it to find ISP or JTAG connectors. I suggest you always do it on a device you will not use or you are not currently using because there is always a chance of bricking the device or shorting circuitry so if you want to do it on your speaker just buy another one and try it on that second one.